# How can I initialize a Reactive Angular2 form using an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

My plan is to store the values of a form in my ngrx store to allow my users to navigate around the site and back to the form if they wish. The idea would be that the values of the form would repopulate from the store using an observable.

here is how I'm doing it currently:

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.images = images;
    this.recipe$ = store.select(recipeBuilderSelector);
    this.recipe$.subscribe(recipe => this.recipe = recipe); // console.log() => undefined
    this.recipeForm = fb.group({
      foodName: [this.recipe.name], // also tried with an OR: ( this.recipe.name || '')
      description: [this.recipe.description]
    })
  }
```

The store is given an initial value which I have seen passes through my selector function properly, but by the time my form is created, I don't think that value has returned. Therefore `this.recipe` is still undefined.

**Is this the wrong approach, or can I somehow ensure that the observable is returned before creating the form?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two options...

**Option 1:**

Use an [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) on the html that displays the form something like

```
<form *ngIf="this.recipe">...</form>
```

**Option 2:**
Use the [async](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) pipe in your template and create your model like:

*component*

```
model: Observable<FormGroup>;    
...
this.model = store.select(recipeBuilderSelector)
    .startWith(someDefaultValue)
    .map((recipe: Recipe) => {
        return fb.group({
            foodName: [recipe.name],
            description: [recipe.description]
        })
    })
```

*template*

```
<app-my-form [model]="(model | async)"></app-my-form>
```

You would have to consider how to handle updates to the store and to the current model.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work this way. `startsWith() does not exist on type Observable`. that function seems to exist only for strings.

Comment: I'm sorry, the method should be `startWith`. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/startwith.md

Comment: `.startWith()` worked on the first iteration, but when the second (dev mode) ran it was again undefined. I got it to work by removing `startWith()` and changing my selector to: `return _.cloneDeep(state.recipebuilder) || someDefaultValue;`

Answer (score 12):

Although adding another layer might seem more complicated, it is much easier to deal with observables by splitting the single component into two: a *container* component and a *presentational* component.

The container component deals only with observables and not with the presentation. The data from any observables is passed to the presentation component via `@Input` properties and the `async` pipe is used:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: "recipe-container",
  template: `<recipe-component [recipe]="recipe$ | async"></recipe-component>`
})
export class RecipeContainer {

  public recipe$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.recipe$ = store.select(recipeBuilderSelector);
  }
}
```

The presentational component receives simple properties and does not have to deal with observables:

```ts
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: "recipe-component",
  template: `...`
})
export class RecipeComponent {

  public recipeForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.recipeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      foodName: [""],
      description: [""]
    });
  }

  @Input() set recipe(value: any) {
    this.recipeForm.patchValue({
      foodName: value.name,
      description: value.description
    });
  }
}
```

The notion of using container and presentational components is a general Redux concept and is explained in [*Presentational and Container Components*](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Comment: I could not get this way to work for me. Somehow the form was being built before the Selector was called

Comment: Yep, I see your point. I should have created the form in the constructor and only applied the changes when the `@Input` was changed. I've updated the answer. Whichever way you decide to go with this, I'd encourage you to look into separating things into container and presentational components, as it does make life easier.

Comment: any criticism or shusson's option 2 answer? I was able to do it without a container by using `[formGroup]="recipe$ | async"`

Comment: You can definitely get it working without the container/presentation separation, but I find the separation beneficial with larger apps. It's up to you to decide whether or not it's worth it in your situation. It's just something to be aware of; there are almost always multiple ways of getting something done. I use container components for all store and service interactions, leaving the presentation components to deal with simple inputs. BTW, I simplified the answer to use an `@Input` setter instead of `OnChanges`.

Comment: @cartant Could you use ChangeStrategy.onPush with @Input() on the presentational layout ?

Comment: @rotemx Using `OnPush` and `@Input` on the presentational component is the essence of the answer, so I'm not sure what you are asking. If you are asking whether or not `OnPush` and `@Input` can be used on a *container* component, then yes, of course you can.

Comment: @cartant ~ the approach in this answer is really clean